# 2 default case in switch

Tags: php, php-7, legacy-code

I have to work on some legacy code. In a part of this code, there are two `default` cases in a `switch`:

```
switch (strtoupper($format)) {
    case '4A0': {$format = array(4767.87,6740.79); break;}
    // etc.
    case 'A3': {$format = array(841.89,1190.55); break;}
    case 'A4': default: {$format = array(595.28,841.89); break;}
    case 'A5': {$format = array(419.53,595.28); break;}
    // etc.
    case 'ROYAL': {$format=array(433.70,663.30 );  break;}
    default: $format = false;
}
```

It should have work before but it can't anymore now (since [PHP7](http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.switch.php) multiple default cases will raise a E_COMPILE_ERROR error, BTW it's a good news!). I want to clean this code (I don't understand why some people added two default in a switch, I think it's weird and dirty) and remove one of the default, but I'm not sure to understand the purpose of that code, so I don't know which one I have to kill.

Assuming **I don't want to break anything**, should I remove the first `default` or the second `default`?

Comment: Write a unit test for it, get it running in the PHP version it works in, then switch to PHP7 and you can refactor at will, safe in the knowledge that you have a test case ensuring the outcomes are the same.

Comment: Just remove all but the last. It's most likely a left over introduced because of that horribly unreadable code style.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier When I wrote "thanks to PHP7", there is no sarcasm. This code is not mine, and I never saw two default case before, so it's a unknown problem for me now, that's why I ask.

Comment: Wow. Down-voted twice, don't understand why...

Comment: @rap-2-h oh sorry, I misunderstood the intent :) as for the dv I would hazard it'd have to do with the quality of the code, or because people think you should think about that on your own.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I think you are not the only one who misunderstood, I think it's why I have been downvoted for a "ok" question ;)